# Python skipped one of my function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using a `tkinter` frame to call another `tkinter` frame. So from frame one i will click a button and it will check if there is a file at C:\ and if the file is not there it should call the `Chrome_gui` function which is another `tkinter` frame at `"def p2(self)"`. When the `Chrome_gui` is called it will create the test file and the `self.p2` will be called again to check if the file is there. But it will become a never ending loop as the function `self.Chrome_gui`is not called. And when i remove `self.p2`, the function `self.Chrome_gui` can be called. So can anyone tell me why it is skipping the `self.Chrome_gui` function?

```
def __init__(self):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    tk.Tk.title(self,"qwerty")
    self.b1 = tk.Button(self, text="P2", command = self.p2)
    self.b1.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = 'EWNS' )


def p2 (self):
            self.values()
    print ('printdwo')
    my_file1 = Path("C:\test.pdf")
    if my_file1.is_file():
        print ("File Found")
    else:
        print ('not found')
        self.Chrome_gui()
        self.p2()


def Chrome_gui(self):
    self.chrome = tk.Tk()
    self.chrome.title('Date')
    self.label = tk.Label(self.chrome, text="", width=20)
    self.label.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    self.c1 = tk.Button(self.chrome, text="Yes", command = self.yes)
    self.c1.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W+E)#side = LEFT)
    global e
    e = ""
    self.c2 = tk.Button(self.chrome, text = "No" , command = self.no)
    self.c2.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W+E)#side = LEFT)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: BTW: string `\t` has special meaning in text (even in path) - it means key `tab` so instead of \ better use \\ or / - C:\\test.pdf or C:/test.pdf

Comment: maybe it run `Chrome_gui` but `p2` loops (and it never exit this loop) and it can't run `root.mainloop()` which creates and draws all windows and widgets.

Comment: BTW: program should use only one `tk.Tk()` which creates main window. To create second/third (sub)window you should use `tk.Toplevel()`. But I think you could use [standard dialogs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm) instead of `Chrome_gui`

Comment: maybe put `self.p2()` in `yes()` method so it will check again only when you click button "Yes". This way you will have no loop inside `p2()`. It would be good to check how many times it try to create file and give up after third time.

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs, I will go test out all your suggestions and I will update the outcome.

Comment: Ok so i have tried using the tk.Toplevel() and it is working now Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looping because your condition `if my_file1.is_file():` is always false so it's always calling `self.p2()` in the else part.

When you're defining a string and you want to put a '\', you have to put '\'. In your case you have '\t' so it will replace it by a tabulation. Replace it by `Path("C:\\test.pdf")`